# Npm vulnerabilities Angular 7

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I have update my angular project from 7.0 to 7.2 and i have this message at the end :

> found 220 vulnerabilities (178 low, 34 moderate, 8 high) in 37100
>   scanned packages   run `npm audit fix` to fix 212 of them.   8
>   vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.

Here some example of the audit :

[image]

Do i need to worry about this message ? How can i fix it ? thank you for your help.

**Edit :**

I have npm audit fix and now have this message :

fixed 212 of 220 vulnerabilities in 37100 scanned packages
  1 package update for 8 vulns involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)

[image]

Solved :

Updated webdriver-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after :

npm audit fix 
and Updated webdriver-manager